# Whenever I send Quickblox login or chat join request it returns authorization error. {JavaScript SDK}

Tags: javascript, request, header, token, quickblox

In the Headers I don't QB-Token! How Can I add that?
I'm successfully creating a session but I cannot handle the other request as it returns an authorization(401) error.

Comment: Did you register and pass correctly your app credentials as parameters for ```QB.init()``` to initialize quickblox sdk?

Comment: Sure! here are my credentials setup ```QB.init(
    APP_ID,
    AUTH_KEY,
    AUTH_SECRET,
    ACCOUNT_KEY,
    CONFIG
  )```

Comment: After you create session what exactly is the method that are given the problem?

Comment: either Sign-up or login methods:
```var params = {
  login: login,
  password: "someSecret",
  full_name: "QuickBlox Test"
};

QB.users.create(params, function(error, result) {
 
});```

```var params = { login: "garry", password: "garry5santos" };

QB.login(params, function(error, result) {
});```

Answer (score 0):

The session is required to put in QB.init if the session token comes from the backend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).